# check constraint cannot execute a function belonging to another DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-function, check-constraints

I want to set a check constraint based on a function which belongs to another database.

My function works fine if I execute it from the database where I would like to set the check constraint:

```
use MyDB1;
select  MyDB2.dbo.MyFunction(1);
--Works fine
```

But when I want to create the check constraint:

```
use MyDB1;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable1]
ADD CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
CHECK (MyDB2.dbo.MyFunction(MyColumn)=1);
GO
```

I get the following error:
4120 A user-defined function name cannot be prefixed with a database name in this context.

Any chance to achieve what I want?

EDIT:
I know it would be possible to create the function in MyDB1 and call it locally in the MyDB1 check constraint.
But I will have to make similar constraints in 3 different databases so it would be better to create the function only once in MyDB2 and call it from the 3 different constraints.

Comment: *"Any chance to achieve what I want?"* Yes, create the function in the same DB as the constraint. You can't have cross database constraints.

Comment: I know that DRY is a good practice, _but_ often in databases this is sacrificed for performance and/or other reasons. Perhaps consider whether the constraint definition is sufficiently complex that you can't define it in three places

Comment: You can create a trigger that validates the result of the function and rollbacks if your condition doesn't met.

Comment: If you must use a scalar function as a constraint, it has to be in the database the constraint is relevant to. A Constraint that references a different database can't be created, and (in my opinion) for good reason. One reason is that if the other database is inaccessible then the constraint will fail, meaning it would be impossible to perform any kind of DML operation on your table.